# The mapping for the solution could not found while opening silverlight application

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

I am trying to open silverlight project. It has 12 projects inside.last two projects does not load properly. i am  trying  to reload those two project a pop up window opened and that is asking download silverlight runtime(silverlight developer.exe). while downloading this software it is giving error message : **A 64 bit version of silverlight is already installed**.

I closed visual studio i reopned same project again last two projects not loadded properly.
Can you please give me any suggestions why i am getting issue.

Comment: I think you developed the application in old version of silverlight. And you laptop/computer has now the latest version. OR. You have corrupted silverlight runtime. So remove the current installation and re-install silverlight runtime again.

Comment: Thanks Gee ! i uninstalled silverlight run-time and i installed. Now i am not getting issue. Thanks once again .

Comment: Good. @Kiran-reddy Accept my answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you developed the application in old version of silverlight. And you laptop/computer has now the latest version.

OR

You have corrupted silverlight runtime. So remove the current installation and re-install silverlight runtime again.